# Macbook Pro 2015 connecting to a TI Sensortag cc2541

Tags: python, sensors, texas-instruments, btle

Background - What I would like to do is to be able to push buttons on a BT sensor and trigger some actions like tweet or play a particular sound etc. I have a TI CC2541 Sensortag that I would like to control with a python program.

Issue - I am unable to get Mac OS X bluetooth to recognize the BLE on TI Sensortag.

Attempts - I installed lightblue which recognizes the sensor. But I am not sure how that can help control the sensor programmatically.
I heard about Bluez in my research, but I guess it is related to linux only systems. I have used Evothings and that can connect to the sensortag through my phone on the same network. I can make small changes to the javascript on evothings studio to capture events from the Sensortag and affect changes on the evothings app.

I am trying to get my Mac to recognize the BLE Sensortag after which I can control the device programmatically. Do I need to buy one of these pluggable BLE dongles to get this to work? OR am I attempting something wrong.

Please advise.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: @amok i have not found a solution yet. But I am only seeing solutions that talk of BLE and Sensors connected to RPi and Arduino. I wonder why the sensor is not recognized out of the box on a mac when it comes with the required BLE hardware. I have since tried fetching RSSI values from LightBlue, that seems fairly accurate, getting individual sensor data must be possible but installing the corresponding blue libraries and then invoking them from my python code , this i have not been able to make it work. In parallel I am working on Bluemix and Node-Red where I have just begun. Thanks for asking

Answer (score 1):

Oh I see now, I can help you with that.

Here's your recipe to success:

1. Make sure that your hardware supports BLE 4.x  ([yours does](http://www.apple.com/macbook/specs/))
2. Link your tag through the preferences/Bluetooth widget
3. Check with lightblue app that you can connect or read some values

If all the above checks out, and it should given the information you provided, then at hardware level you're golden.

At software level, there are many ways to connect and retrieve data. You can use XCODE and build a native OSX app or you can build a NodeJS app to retrieve data from the tag.

On this [blog](http://iamsensoria.com/post/134004915304/raspberry-pi-and-sensor-tag-part-iii?is_related_post=1) post you find all you need for the Node scenario. It is documented for the Raspberry Pi however, the code for running this elsewhere, including OSX, is exactly the same

The code is hosted here and I keep it up to date as I make more advancements.
https://github.com/kywix/iamsblog/tree/master/SensorTag

Shortly:

1. Open terminal and git clone that repo
2. cd into the folder SensorTag
3. type npm install (to install all the libraries necessary)
4. node logger.js  to run the basic example
5. turn on your device

btw on the same repo you will find python code as well. I blog regularly about the Sensor Tag.

I will make note of creating a post just for folks like you that seek this type of info, I have been there..

Comment: thanks for your response and offer for help, I am sure I'll study your blog carefully as I go along my IOT projects. Of the steps you listed, the challenge is Step 2. LightBlue works fine, able to recognize and displays some characteristics and the RSSI. I bought a BT 4 dongle and tried nvram commands to switch btwn the internal and the new external BT. I also tried IO tools for Xcode to switch the HCI controller, but I am not able to get the sensor tag to be recognized. The same dongle works perfectly on a PC. On another note, I have made satisfactory progress on Node-Red and MQTT ! Thanks!

Comment: @bhanu were you ever able to get this working on a Mac? Any chance you could share the code? I've been struggling with the same problem for several days now.

Comment: Yes, I did. On my blog code and explanation of everything http://iamsensoria.com -- have fun!